# Ansible ec2.py dynamic inventory errors: ImportError: cannot import name 'ec2'

Tags: python, ansible, boto3

My current machine crashed and I have to setup ansible again on the new one using the same methodologies but It seems I am missing somethings. I need to use version 2.X for consistency reasons as we have not upgraded yet.

I heavily used ec2.py and ec2.ini so when I run

```
~ python /Users/joseph/infrastructure_as_code/ansible_projects/inventory/ec2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File  "/Users/joseph/infrastructure_as_code/ansible_projects/inventory/ec2.py", line 172, in <module>
from ansible.module_utils import ec2 as ec2_utils
ImportError: cannot import name 'ec2' from 'ansible.module_utils'  (/Users/joseph/.pyenv/versions/pypy3.8-7.3.7/lib/pypy3.8/site-  packages/ansible/module_utils/__init__.py)
```

Here is my setup .Fresh MacBook Pro M1.

```
#Mac, no prior ansible installation either brew or pip
#Check Python version
➜  ~ python --version
Python 3.8.12 (9ef55f6fc369, Oct 25 2021, 05:10:01)
[PyPy 7.3.7 with GCC Apple LLVM 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)]

#Check version used by shebang
➜  ~ /usr/bin/env python --version
Python 3.8.12 (9ef55f6fc369, Oct 25 2021, 05:10:01)
[PyPy 7.3.7 with GCC Apple LLVM 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)]

## Check ansible version. Had to use version 2 for now. Installed with pip over python installed by peen
➜  ~ ansible --version
ansible 2.10.17
  config file = /Users/joseph/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/joseph/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Users/joseph/.pyenv/versions/pypy3.8-7.3.7/lib/pypy3.8/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /Users/joseph/.pyenv/versions/pypy3.8-7.3.7/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.12 (9ef55f6fc369, Oct 25 2021, 05:10:01)[PyPy 7.3.7 with GCC  Apple LLVM 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)]

#Run ec2.py inventory script
➜  ~ python   /Users/joseph/infrastructure_as_code/ansible_projects/inventory/ec2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File   "/Users/joseph/infrastructure_as_code/ansible_projects/inventory/ec2.py ", line 172, in <module>
from ansible.module_utils import ec2 as ec2_utils
ImportError: cannot import name 'ec2' from 'ansible.module_utils' (/Users/joseph/.pyenv/versions/pypy3.8-7.3.7/lib/pypy3.8/site-   packages/ansible/module_utils/__init__.py)

#$PATH
             /Users/joseph/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin:/Users/joseph/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv- virtualenv/shims:/Users/joseph/.pyenv/shims:/Users/joseph/.pyenv/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

## Content of ~/.ansible.cfg
[defaults]
interpreter_python=/Users/joseph/.pyenv/shims/python

## Which python
/Users/joseph/.pyenv/shims/python

## other python
➜  ~ pyenv versions
   system
   3.10.2
   3.8.12
   ansible-2x
   * pypy3.8-7.3.7 (set by /Users/joseph/.pyenv/version)
   pypy3.8-7.3.7/envs/ansible-2x
```

I have read couple of solution around about the PATH and had high hopes about the interpreter_python setting in the config file but none of that worked. So I am not sure what is wrong were, I have also switched to different version of python but it did nothing. Not sure what's missing , I would appreciate some hand in fixing this. Thanks in advance

Comment: `ansible-galaxy collection install amazon.aws.ec2` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have ansible v2.10.17 whereas that file only exists in the v2.9 series: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.9.27/lib/ansible/module_utils/ec2.py

- 404: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.12.2/lib/ansible/module_utils/ec2.py
- 404: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.11.8/lib/ansible/module_utils/ec2.py
- 404: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.10.17/lib/ansible/module_utils/ec2.py

In the future, `pip freeze` will emit a requirements.txt file with the versions pinned to the current ones in use, which can help this kind of drift

Comment: moving onto aws_ec2 plugin instead. Thanks for the clarification.