# Issue reaching boxes behind a bastion host with ansible was_ec2 dynamic inventory plugin

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, ansible, ssh-tunnel, bastion-host

I have gone round a little and I can say this post is not a duplicate. I have been fairly using Ansible 2.9.x and connectivity to the bastion host has always worked fine for me using the ec2.py dynamic inventory . I am switching to the the ansible was_ec2 plugin and one of the reason is even on this other [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71133214/ansible-ec2-py-dynamic-inventory-errors-importerror-cannot-import-name-ec2/71136037#71136037) post of mine.

I have gleaned information below are my inventory file and ansible.cfg file

```
#myprovile.aws_ec2.yml
plugin: amazon.aws.aws_ec2
boto_profile: my profile
strict: True
regions:
  - eu-west-1
  - eu-central-1
  - eu-north-1
keyed_groups:
  - key: tags
    prefix: tag
hostnames:
  - ip-address
  # - dns-name
  # - tag:Name
  - private-ip-address
compose:
  ansible_host: private_ip_address

# folder/project level ansible.cfg  configuration
[defaults]
roles_path            = roles
host_key_checking     = False
hash_behaviour        = merge ### Note to self: Extremely important settings
interpreter_python    = auto  ### Note to self: Very important settings for running    from localhost

[inventory]
enable_plugins = aws_ec2, host_list, script, auto, yaml, ini, toml
# inventory = plugin_inventory/bb.aws_ec2.yaml
```

The inventory has group_vars files

```
➜  plugin_inventory git:(develop) ✗ tree
.
├── myprovile.aws_ec2.yml
└── group_vars
    ├── tag_Name_main_productname_uat_jumpbox.yml
    ├── tag_Name_main_productname_uat_mongo.yml
    ├── tag_Name_main_productname_uat_mongo_arb.yml
    ├── tag_Name_main_productname_uat_mysql.yml
    └── tag_Name_xxx.yml
    └── tag_Name_yyy.yml
```

To get to mongo db which is in private subnet, the group_vars files looks like below

```
#ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i {{ hostvars.localhost.reg_jumpbox_ssh_key }} -W %h:%p -q ubuntu@{{ hostvars.localhost.reg_jumpbox_facts.instances.0.public_ip_address }}"'
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ~/Dropbox/creds/pemfiles/ProductUATOps.pem -W %h:%p -q ubuntu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"'
```

Each time I run the command

```
AWS_PROFILE=myprofile ansible -i ~/infrastructure_as_code/ansible_projects/productname/plugin_inventory/myprofile.aws_ec2.yml tag_Name_main_productname_uat_mongo -m ping -u ubuntu --private-key ~/Dropbox/creds/pemfiles/ProductUATOps.pem -vvvv
```

it doesn't connect and the full output and some other information are at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/QytD3kmB).

Now something odd I have see is that, even though in the ansible.cfg there is the `host_key_checking= False` I still find the following in the command `Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?`.

I have also seen that it's looking for `~/.ssh/known_hosts2\`, `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` and `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2` but `~/.ssh/known_hosts` is what's there.

There is also one confusing error in the logs `"module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: /Users/joseph/.pyenv/shims/python: not found\r\n"`. But the python installation with pyenv has been consistent, os wise:

```
➜  ~ which python
/Users/joseph/.pyenv/shims/python

➜  ~ python --version
Python 3.8.12 (9ef55f6fc369, Oct 25 2021, 05:10:01)
[PyPy 7.3.7 with GCC Apple LLVM 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)]

➜  ~ ls -lh /Users/joseph/.pyenv/shims/python
-rwxr-xr-x  1 joseph  staff   183B Feb 14 22:47   /Users/joseph/.pyenv/shims/python

➜  ~ /usr/bin/env python --version
Python 3.8.12 (9ef55f6fc369, Oct 25 2021, 05:10:01)
[PyPy 7.3.7 with GCC Apple LLVM 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)]
```

I suspect the error is due to the fact that something is preventing the fingerprints from getting into the known hosts file  and I am tempted to simulate the ssh tunneling manually myself but I would like to understand why this is happening and whether it's because this is a new machine. Can anyone shed some light on this for me . Thanks

Comment: This question is multiple problems at once, and for sure would benefit from an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), both in terms of trying to digest what you're asking, as well as helping you to understand what, **exactly**, you need help with

Comment: One will observe that your `ansible_ssh_common_args` only contains `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` _inside_ the `ProxyCommand`, so only the _proxy_ connection was told not to prompt, leaving the outer `ssh` to behave as normal

Comment: @mdaniel , thanks for the comment. I also was under the impression that the outer ssh was taken care of by the `host_key_checking= False` of Ansible.cfg :) . If that isn't the case, I am grateful if you could show how to achieve that. 
The MCVE is a bit complex to realize, that's why I tried as much as possible to provide current configurations. In all I would like to get the ssh tunneling through the jumpbox working with ansible. Thanks

Comment: Running `ansible-config dump` using your cited `ansible.cfg` emits `AnsibleOptionsError: Invalid value "merge ##...` so I'm guessing it just silently ate your config file, or isn't even using the one you think it is. Maybe try `env ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False ansible-playbook ...` and see if it behaves differently

Comment: @mdaniel, this as suspected is the smoking gun. Thanks for pointing this out . I fixed the comment on the config. It's fine now. Thanks so much. Can you create your answer so I mark it as solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running `ansible-config dump` using that `ansible.cfg`, it emits `AnsibleOptionsError: Invalid value "merge ##...` so it seems ansible just silently ate the config file, or may be using a different one

It seems that while `#` is a supported *beginning of line* comment character, ansible-config (as of 2.12.1) only tolerates `;` as and end of line comment character

```
[defaults]
roles_path            = roles
host_key_checking     = False
hash_behaviour        = merge ;;; Note to self: Extremely important settings
interpreter_python    = auto  ;;; Note to self: Very important settings for running    from localhost

[inventory]
enable_plugins = aws_ec2, host_list, script, auto, yaml, ini, toml
```